# Is there an easy way to get Type object from C# type name

Tags: c#

I want to create Type object from string value, e.g., "int", "long". I know I can create Type object from .net framework type name, like
Type t = Type.GetType("System.Int32").

Is there a built-in way to do same from C# type, "int", "long".

Answer (score 4):

The .Net framework itself (including the Reflection library) is completely unaware of C#'s type keywords.
Therefore, you'll need to do this youself.

You can create a `Dictionary<string, Type>`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Given I didn't understand your question here is a link to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320948/possible-to-get-type-of-an-aliased-type-in-c) asked previously

```
typeof(int), typeof(string);
```

Comment: This will not generate type from string.