# Loading a string type from a variable string (like variable variables, and reflection)

Tags: c#, reflection, localization

```
var mystring = "MyCompany.MyType.Localization.Strings.MyString"
```

In C#, is there a way I could fill it up such that

```
var abc = GetReflectedValue(mystring);
```

Is reflection the only way? (how?) Or any more efficient ways?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to get Type object from C# type name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929026/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-type-object-from-c-type-name)

Comment: what are you actually trying to do here? Load locale based strings?

Comment: I have a string, "MyCompany.MyClass", it's static, it has a property on it called "Foo". I want to call "MyCompany.Class"'s "Foo" property. I have all of this provided as user input, not in code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you are trying to do. Do you mean create an instance of an object given only it's string type name? If so, use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx):

```
var item = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(mystring));
```

Comment: Type.GetType() keeps saying null, it seems like my shared dll may not be loaded. Does my assembly need to be loaded for this to work?