# How to get alias of a type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

Is it possible to implement a method like

```
string GetFriendlyName(Type type) { ... }
```

in .NET that will return the [CLR alias](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88418.aspx) of the type, if possible? In this case `GetFriendlyName(typeof(Foo))` will return "Foo", but `GetFriendlyName(typeof(int))` will return "int" instead of "Int32" like in [MemberInfo.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Those are C# specific aliases not defined by the CLR. It can be confusing to non-C# developers if you display them in another context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Well*, I don't believe there is no way to do it programmaticly. You can use a [`dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead of like;

```
public static readonly Dictionary<Type, string> aliases = new Dictionary<Type, string>()
{
    { typeof(string), "string" },
    { typeof(int), "int" },
    { typeof(byte), "byte" },
    { typeof(sbyte), "sbyte" },
    { typeof(short), "short" },
    { typeof(ushort), "ushort" },
    { typeof(long), "long" },
    { typeof(uint), "uint" },
    { typeof(ulong), "ulong" },
    { typeof(float), "float" },
    { typeof(double), "double" },
    { typeof(decimal), "decimal" },
    { typeof(object), "object" },
    { typeof(bool), "bool" },
    { typeof(char), "char" }
};
```

**EDIT**: I found two questions to provide an answer

- [Is there a way to get a type's alias through reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362884/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-types-alias-through-reflection)
- [Possible to get type of an aliased type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320948/possible-to-get-type-of-an-aliased-type-in-c)

Comment: +1, i was about to post something same !

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way :

```
private string GetFriendlyName(Type type)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> alias = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {typeof (byte).Name, "byte"},
            {typeof (sbyte).Name, "sbyte"},
            {typeof (short).Name, "short"},
            {typeof (ushort).Name, "ushort"},
            {typeof (int).Name, "int"},
            {typeof (uint).Name, "uint"},
            {typeof (long).Name, "long"},
            {typeof (ulong).Name, "ulong"},
            {typeof (float).Name, "float"},
            {typeof (double).Name, "double"},
            {typeof (decimal).Name, "decimal"},
            {typeof (object).Name, "object"},
            {typeof (bool).Name, "bool"},
            {typeof (char).Name, "char"},
            {typeof (string).Name, "string"}
        };
    return alias.ContainsKey(type.Name) ? alias[type.Name] : type.Name;
}
```

I suggest you to make `alias` dictionary  `static readonly` for performance benefit.